# reading GMDB libraries ( for GNet) in C# in Linux for Mono

Tags: c#, linux, sqlite, mono

I'm developing cross-platform application that use SQLite for reading GNet databases ( gmdb, that is an SQLite database). In Windows, I use by System.Data.SQLite - all works excellent. But for Linux ( Debian or Ubuntu) I try to run my application by Mono, and Mono.Data.SqliteClient can not open gmdb file - it not recognize it as database. By the way, sqlite browser can view the same database file. Sqlite3 installed on system

I try to open file by using connection string as "URI=file:/[path]/Data.gmdb". When I try to open connection, I received error "file is encrypted or it is not a database". ( in windows, application opens the same file . And SQLite browser successfully opens this DB in Linux )

Comment: If your goal is to go cross platform, please use .NET Core not Mono today. Most of the NuGet packages now are .NET Core ready.

Comment: No, goal is passing Winforms app to Linux. .net core is not friends with WinForms

Comment: Mono WinForms won't be friendly to you either. To write a GUI app on Linux, seriously consider other alternatives (on .NET Core) out there, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea

Comment: Thanks , but currently I can't change infrastructure of program- it is existing ( and large) program written for Window, and I need to port it for Linux. For this question- i'm not find solution, and I simply wrote shared library on C with usage of SQLite standard library

Answer (score 0):

I can't find solution for Mono C#. But it is easy enough was to wrote library on C with usage of standard libsqlite-dev